# How do I only show data in a view where current time is between starttime and endtime column of the events table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named events. This table holds every event booked within a year. I want to create a view where I can return the info of an event occurring right now. the table contains a starttime and endtime column.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I already tried to use systimefrompart, getdate etc... I already am getting all events that occur today by using the column startdate:

```
SELECT id, starttime, endtime, enddate, startdate
FROM     dbo.events
WHERE  (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)
```

![Result] https://i.stack.imgur.com/skCz6.png

I expect to get the event that is occurring right now.

Comment: I don't think your query does what you think it does. That query would require that the value of startdate be exactly the same time as the current system time. But more importantly, you haven't asked a question here. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question. And then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for ideas of the kinds of details you should post.

Comment: Sorry I changed the question. Hope iT is up to standards now thnx

Comment: It isn't about adding a question mark somewhere. It is about explaining what you want to accomplish. This almost always requires some knowledge of the tables and some sample data, neither of which is here. Actually reading the links I sent would be a great start. People here want to help you but we don't like just randomly guessing at solutions.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lange, I Will edit the post further when I am home en put in sample data.

Comment: That would be great. I look forward to your update so we can help you solve this. Or maybe look the answer from Squirrel. It seems to answer the question you are asking.

Comment: Indeed i Will try this too when i get home. Kind regards

Comment: What is the data type of `starttime` and `endtime`? Do they only contain date and not time?

Comment: they contain both, I updated the question with image and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried a combination between the two awnsers:

the code i used is:

```
SELECT id AS Event, starttime, endtime
FROM     dbo.events
WHERE  (starttime <= sysdatetimeoffset()) AND (endtime >= sysdatetimeoffset())
```

this gives me the result i needed.

Thanx everybody

Answer (score 2):

`getdate()` return date & time. `cast()` or `convert()` it to date data type before compare with your columns

```
Select * 
From   Events 
Where  startdate <= convert(date, getdate())
And    enddate   >= convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: Well I think `endtime` should be compared to *tomorrow*, not today. If endtime is at 3:00 AM today, or 3:00 PM today, or 11:59 PM today, it will not be `>= convert(date, getdate())` because that's today *at midnight*. Similarly, if an event started at 3:00 AM today, it will not be `<= convert(date, getdate())`. If you really want to know about *right now* vs. *before or after today at midnight* you really should avoid the converts to date altogether.

Comment: I Tried the following:

    `SELECT id AS Event, starttime, endtime, startdate, enddate
    FROM     dbo.events
    WHERE  (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) 
    AND (starttime <= GETDATE()) AND (endtime >= GETDATE())`

Comment: @seanlange, I edited in different ways but still no luck.

Comment: @bregtV i see you have separate `startdate` and `startime` column Do you need to take into consideration `starttime` and `endtime` ?

Comment: @Squirrel indeed, because I need the events that are happening at this time. I didn't explain it as correctly as it should be. The solution is below. This does exactly what it needs to do for me. You helped me a lot with your code, I reused a part of it. Thnx for this.